# flush not working with scripts or styles

Tags: php, hyperlink, flush

I've encountered a problem with 
flush():

```
<?php
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Update</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap_3.3.7.min.css">-->
 <!--<script src="./js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i<3; $i++){
 echo "<br> Line to show.";
 ob_flush();
 flush();
 sleep(1);
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If I uncomment any line the flush() will do nothing and the page will be shown after the script is finished. But if they are commented the page works just fine. What's the matter?

Found out that the content is actually flushed but the browser wait for the script end. But on the other server content shown instantly.

Comment: You have short tags enabled?

Comment: just looked at phpinfo. short_open_tag On

Comment: Okay, so the PHP should be executing, it doesn't show in the source, right? Can you explain `If I uncomment any line`? I only see 2 HTML lines commented out currently.

Comment: actually there are 4 lines that are commented right now: 2 stylesheets from bootstrap and 2 script for jQuery and bootstrap. If they are commented the page flush output as it should (when  ob_flush and flush are called) but if the page has any script or stylesheet it will output only when the script is done